# DTAP - Staging Presentation Server on Acceptance Environment

Tags: 2013, infrastructure

Was just looking at the latest Tridion 2013 [online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US&action=search&query=DTAP&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1372234714224&currentQuery=DTAP&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_36B0F887226A4CBFA28E28313AD25AE0&query=&scope=&filename=DTAPSetup.xml&docid=concept_36B0F887226A4CBFA28E28313AD25AE0&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=) (login required) on DTAP and noticed that the Acceptance environment contains a Staging Presentation Server.

**Is that a typical set-up in peoples experience?**

I'd always thought of Staging as a part of Production to allow Content Editors to validate content. That's not normally the focus of an Acceptance environment - content here is usually to support any new application code that's being evaluated - would Editors really need to Stage/Preview first?

I know Tridion has to support a wide range of business needs and I'm coming from my own narrow experiences, but I just wondered.

Comment: Yes, *up to* 8 environments in a fully built DTAP setup (how else will you test Experience Manager). I wondered the same: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11475217/395495. +1 for asking on Tridion StackExchange.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

Most customers have sites the behave differently on staging then live, it might have for instance make use of SiteEdit or the Experience Manager. This means that your code needs to be built, tested and accepted in both versions: staging and live. Therefor, most DTAP environments will have a staging and live site in development, test and acceptance as well.

Comment: +1. Sometimes organizations might consolidate and use less. But as long as none of the environments publish to the *same* Live or Staging, we're good. :-)